# Are there any offline tutorials for Mathematica?

Tags: reference-request

As [can be seen from my questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1990/mbork?tab=questions), I am struggling to make Mathematica do something useful.  The amount of tutorials on the Wolfram web site is a bit overwhelming, especially that I don't have too much time to read them.  However, I am commuting for about 90 minutes per day, and having the Mathematica documentation (even just the one that comes with the software) in Kindle-friendly format (I'd even accept pdf) would be a great thing for me.  Can I find a downloadable version of Mma docs (in pdf, or even better, in epub/mobi) anywhere?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/)?

Comment: Nope, thanks!  BTW: thank you for your book on Mma programming, I already have it on my Kindle and have read quite a bit!  (And could you make this an answer, so that I can accept it?)

Comment: No problem. Glad if it helps.

Comment: What about [this](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+&+engineering/book/978-0-387-95011-2)? Its a nice book by springer.. downloadable..

Comment: Well... 70 EUR - waaay above my price range.  I'd pay, say up to 10 USD; this price looks more like a joke for me.  Of course, with 1200+pages it might be fair, but I guess 80% of those pages would be of no use to me.  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica's documentation is also available online in the pdf format, as a tutorial collection. The place to look for it is [here](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/). Also, some books on Mathematica are now available as kindle editions, from  [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=digital-text&field-keywords=mathematica). Finally, for those books which have Mathematica notebook versions, you can probably make a pdf from those notebooks for a personal use, if that does not violate the book's license.